# Radiobutton selection always returns the last value

Tags: javascript, html

I have tried everything to get this working, but it still returns the last value (54) even when any of the other radiobuttons are selected. Can anyone see anything i am missing?

```
<div class="rsize">
<input type="radio" class="item_size" value="50" id="r-1" name="r-group-1" checked>
<label for="r-1">50</label>
</div>

<div class="rsize">
<input type="radio" class="item_size" value="52" id="r-2" name="r-group-1">
<label for="r-2">52</label>
</div>

<div class="rsize">
<input type="radio" class="item_size" value="54" id="r-3" name="r-group-1">
<label for="r-3">54</label>
</div>
```

Comment: What code are you using to determine which one is selected?

Comment: how you are reading radio button info. Do you mean on submit or any js operation

Comment: Are you sure they are not working? I tested that code in a sample HTML page I created and it's perfectly fine. How are you checking which one is selected?

Comment: Last time I ask any questions on here. All these negative marks.

Comment: Thanks Chris/Amritpal and Chevi for the reply. Its a javascript shopping cart, so I am sending the data from the item_size to a cart script. I have to send the item_size variable a value.

Comment: Your question asks why something doesn't work, yet you haven't included *any* of the code that tries to retrieve this value!  Of *course* you're getting downvoted!

Comment: There is no item_size _variable_ defined here. Are you accessing the value associated with the _class_ item_size instead of the _name_ r-group-1?

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery, I believe this should work:

```
var value = $("input[@name=r-group-1]:checked").val();
```